# Three's mobile broadband

Tags: 12.10, 3g, broadband, usb-modeswitch

I've recently downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 and it seems great. I just can't get my Three Ireland mifi dongle to work at all. When I plug it in, it only recognizes it as a storage devise. Any ideas on how to establish a permanent connection to this mifi dongle? I'm in Ireland and running a Dell Inspiron 1520 with 3GB of RAM and using the Huawei E586 mifi device. I really want to continue using this OS, but is everything this complicated to get up and running on it?

Comment: The Huawei E586 is a personal hotspot, so shouldn't you log into the provided WiFi network to access the internet instead of plugging it into your machine?

Comment: The tag 'mobile' relates to using **Ubuntu** on portable devices, such as a smartphone or smaller tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this by:

**(a.)** Plugging in a USB WiFi adapter to your Dell laptop, or using its inbuilt WiFi capability, **OR**

**(b.)** Finding the correct USB mode-switch settings, so that it (your USB device) switches back to being a modem (and not just a storage device).

---

**Some Background:**

Back in *Windows*-land, someone had the 'bright' idea that, as all devices need a 'new' driver, any newly plugged-in device should first 'pretend' to be a USB storage device - and attempt to auto-load the driver (stored for that purpose on the device). Then, when the driver starts up it knows to send a command to switch the USB device back into being 'whatever'.

However, Linux (and in particular **Ubuntu**) does not need lots of new drivers. *More importantly, having a device attempt to auto-load a driver (or any **executable code**) is plain dangerous - and may also breach **security policy** and/or be prevented by **anti-virus** software (or similar protective measures).*

Instead **Ubuntu** (and other Linux variants) provides the '*USB mode switch*' function, complete with a large (and growing) list of brands / devices, and the data needed to control them. Unless you are using an unusual (or new) device, a simple update will usually resolve these sorts of issues.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply and sorry about the mobile thing. I'm a complete beginner at this so it all looked like chinese to me I'm looking to find out how to get ubuntu to pick up the wifi signal. Its fine on windows but when I boot up ubunto or zorin I cant get and wifi at all. Surely its something small and nothing overly complicated. Its so frustrating cause I have to do everything on my phone when tryin to fix it so can't go online and update or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers off the Huawei site worked perfectly for me! Make sure you read the instructions and it's easy going, took about 30 seconds. 
http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/downloads/detail/index.htm?id=13971