# Wireless doesn't work in 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, internet, usb-modeswitch

I have Ubuntu 12.10. I have cabled in my TP Link Wi-Fi USB adpter but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me where can I find drivers for linux? My model is TL-WN722N at 150 Mb/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to investigate 'USB mode switch' settings to support your particular modem. Otherwise, it will look like a USB storage device to Ubuntu.

---

See answer in: [USB mode switch - Some Background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221288/threes-mobile-broadband)

Answer (score 1):

What's the output of your ifconfig and iwconfig commands?

Have you tried the ndiswrapper approach? http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=TP-Link_TL-WN722N